# How to randomly pick numpy arrays without overlaps

Tags: python, numpy

I have 8 1x2 matrices in varaibles

```
a1=numpy.array([-3,4])
```

I want to pick 6 of these matrices randomly.

```
b= random.sample([a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8], 6)
```

Thought something like this but it's printing

```
[array([-3,4]), array([-4,5]) ....]
```

I actually want to make these codes in 6x2 after randomly picking, and I'm thinking of using numpy.vstack .

Plz help me.

Comment: What do you mean by "without overlaps"? What is the expected output, and what's wrong with the actual output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wrap the sampling code with `np.array` as follows:

```
b = np.array(random.sample([a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8], 6))
```

It gives a `numpy array` with a 6x2 shape

Comment: Don't forget to upvote my answer and mark it as correct ;)